# Pipe command output to input of running/backgrounded command

Tags: bash, io-redirection, job-control

In Bash 4.X It it possible to do something like:

```
command that expects input &
echo some output | %1
```

Where %1 represents the first backgrounded command?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just do `echo some output | command that expects input &`?

Comment: It was a hypothetical question that came to my mind when thinking about ; for instance; doing rm -i * on a dir with tons of files, and wanting to then just change the command to yes|rm -i, for example.

Comment: I still don't understand the point. The example you gave expects no input. If a command expects input there is no point in launching it before that input is available. In any case, hypothetical questions are [off topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hypothetical situation and not a specific problem.

Comment: rm -i will expect a y or n for every file passed to it.  I am talking about (in this example) using the yes command to simply answer y to every prompt that gets generated by the rm command.  It really isn't so hard to understand, is it?

Comment: Apparently not 'cause John seems to have understood it. Sorry, I hadn't.

Comment: This overzealous moderation is the worst part of SE. There is absolutely nothing off-topic about this question. It neither subjective nor open-ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you start:

```
rm -i -- * &
```

`rm` has been started with whatever stdin was in your shell at the time you invoked that command.

If it was the terminal, then `rm` will typically be suspended (with the SIGTTIN signal) as soon as it tried to read from it (since it's not in the foreground process group of the terminal).

If you want it to read from something else, you have to tell it to reopen its file descriptor 0 on something else.

You could do that with a debugger (here assuming you're on Linux):

```
rm_pid=$!
coproc yes
gdb --pid="$rm_pid" --batch \
    -ex "call close(0)" \
    -ex "call open(\"/proc/$$/fd/$COPROC\", 0)" /bin/rm
kill -s CONT "$rm_pid"
```

Above, we're starting `yes` in background with its stdin and stdout redirected to a pipe. The other end of that pipe is in the shell (process `$$`) on file descriptor `${COPROC[0]}` aka `$COPROC`.

Then, with `gdb`, we're telling `rm` to close its fd 0, and reopen it on that same pipe.

Comment: This is some true wizardry.

Comment: After a long time, I switched to this incredible answer because yours was far superior to the previously selected one.  Thanks Stephane, you always have amazing answers.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but you need a little bit more.

When you send a program to the background you're detaching it from `stdin` associated with your terminal. You need to start it up instead with an alternate input, in this case a pipe.

```
$ mkfifo alternate_input
$ command_that_expects_input < alternate_input
```

You've now assigned the pipe file (`alternate_input`) as the `stdin` for the process `command_that_expects_input`. To send input, simply put something into the pipe.

```
$ echo foo > alternate_input
```

In this case the string `foo` becomes is transferred to `stdin` for `command_that_expects_input`.

Comment: Excellent, this is a good solution.

Comment: @gleventhal: if this better answers your question you should select it for posterity.

Comment: Done.  The one thing missing from your answer is exactly how I should take the job from the background and perform redirection on it.  Mind specifying how to do so?

Comment: You have to do the redirection before it goes to the background, or you can program it to open a predetermined `stdin`.

Comment: The point of the question was how to do it retroactively though.

Answer (score 1):

The way you postulate, no. As terdon says, it's much easier if you know you need to pipe input in the first place. In the rare (so rare I've never encountered it) case where a program expects no input now but will expect input in the future, you can set up a named pipe as the input to that process, background it, then send output of a later-started process to the same named pipe, but you have to set the named pipe up beforehand.

Comment: Thanks.  I was more thinking of a situation where you set a flag to prompt, or forgot to set a flag to not prompt (i.e. rm -i or yum without -y) and wanted to retroactively change that.

Comment: There's no way to do that. Rather, the only want to do that is to kill and restart the process with the flag you meant to set.